# Why does ViTForMaskedImageModeling not construct the original image correctly?

Tags: neural-networks, python, computer-vision, transformers

I was trying to use masked image modeling in huggingface and I saw [ViTForMaskedImageModeling](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/vit#transformers.ViTForMaskedImageModeling) in their documentation but I did not understand how it reconstructs the original image `loss, reconstructed_pixel_values = outputs.loss, outputs.reconstruction`
also, it doesn't reconstruct the original image correctly. It gives me noise.

```
url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")
model = ViTForMaskedImageModeling.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")

num_patches = (model.config.image_size // model.config.patch_size) ** 2
pixel_values = image_processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
# create random boolean mask of shape (batch_size, num_patches)
bool_masked_pos = torch.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1, num_patches)).bool()

outputs = model(pixel_values, bool_masked_pos=bool_masked_pos)
loss, reconstructed_pixel_values = outputs.loss, outputs.reconstruction

reconstructed_pixel_values = reconstructed_pixel_values.detach().numpy()
reconstructed_pixel_values = np.transpose(reconstructed_pixel_values[0], (1, 2, 0))

plt.imshow(reconstructed_pixel_values)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `ViTForMaskedImageModeling` adds an additional `decoder` [layer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/102370544044e020cc435f96dcada668e35d7aea/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L643) that doesn't exist in the pretrained model provided at `"google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k"`. This would mean the pixel predictions are coming from a randomly initialized layer (thus why the reconstructions are just noise)

This warning also appears in the code you provided that supports this:

> Some weights of ViTForMaskedImageModeling were not initialized from the model checkpoint at google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k and are newly initialized: ['embeddings.mask_token', 'decoder.0.weight', 'decoder.0.bias']